# A simple demo Windows 10 service that listens on a TCP port?

Tags: windows

For testing, I would like to have very simple server that can function as an actual Windows 10 service, and listens on a TCP port.

For one, I simply thought of running `python3 -m http.server 8000` - however, this runs in "foreground", and definitely not a Windows service.

Then I found https://gist.github.com/jorgepsmatos/9aa0fef750baccf6d6abe457b911afef - which is seemingly an actual Windows service wrapper around a web server.

The problem is, the web server is SimpleHTTPServer which is Python2 (Python3 is http.server), and the rest of it seems to be written for Python2 as well.

In any case, after some hacking I got to this:

```
C:\tmp\win_serv_py_http_git>python.exe Server.py install
Installing service PythonHttpServer
copying host exe ...
copying helper dll ...
Service installed

C:\tmp\win_serv_py_http_git>D:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe Server.py start
Starting service PythonHttpServer
Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

So, I can't really run it - and not sure if its even worth the bother to get the above to work, as in the end I just need it as a "dummy" in a larger test.

That being said, is there any kind of "basic demo" of a Windows service that listens on a TCP port - preferably downloadable as an already built executable (so the language does not really matter; as long as it is trivially simple, and I set the port it listens on) - which I could "install", "start"/"stop" or "remove" as a Windows Service?

Comment: maybe https://techgenix.com/windows-7-simple-tcpip-services-what-how/ ; https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000121389/how-to-install-simple-tcp-ip-services

Answer (score 0):

I just spent some time building this for ya...should work fine as I just tested it as well on Windows 11...should work on 10 as well. Fun little project as I had never completed this before.

Make sure you've downloaded [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) - the latest as of this post is [v3.11.5](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.5/python-3.11.5-amd64.exe)

**Python Server:** (save this as ***testserver.py*** or whatever you would like.)

```
import socket

def start_tcp_listener():
    host = '0.0.0.0'  # Listen on all available network interfaces
    port = 8080

    listener_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    listener_socket.bind((host, port))
    listener_socket.listen(5)

    print(f"Listening for incoming connections on {host}:{port}")

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = listener_socket.accept()
        print(f"Client connected from {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}")

        # Send a welcome message to the client
        client_socket.send(b"Welcome to the server!")

        while True:
            try:
                # Receive data from the client
                data = client_socket.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break  # No more data, close the connection

                print(f"Received from client: {data.decode()}")

                # Send a response back to the client
                client_socket.send(b"Server received your message!")
            except ConnectionResetError:
                break  # Connection closed by the client

        # Close the client socket when done
        client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_tcp_listener()
```

**Python Client:** (save this as ***testclient.py*** or whatever you like.)

```
import socket

def connect_to_server():
    host = '127.0.0.1'  # Replace with the actual IP address of your server
    port = 8080  # Make sure it matches the port your server is listening on

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        client_socket.connect((host, port))
        print(f"Connected to server at {host}:{port}")
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("Connection refused. Make sure the server is running.")
        return

    # Send data to the server if needed
    client_socket.send(b"Hello, server!")

    # Receive data from the server if needed
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print("Received from server:", data.decode())

    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_server()
```

Then open / save this code within [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) or *your preferred IDE.*

**Working examples:**
[image: Server]
[image: Client]

It is set to kill the connection after the test is successful, but you can easily modify that by commenting out `client_socket.close()` on line 35 in testserver.py, and `client_socket.close()` in line 23 in testclient.py by adding # in front of each respective line.